# Search two location points in one go using Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, location, geospatial, latitude-longitude, database

Say I have a document, which looks like

```
{loc:{start:[x,y],end:[x1,y1]}}
```

with *2dsphere* index, and I want to search for all the documents that have the same start and end points in one query. Is it possible to do it in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A geospatial index can only cover one field with a legacy coordinate pair (array with two values) or a valid [GeoJSON Point, Polygon or LineString](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html). That means you can only index either the start-position or the end-position with a geospatial index.

But this is not a problem when you are searching for an exact match. A 2dsphere index offers [some additional geographical operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-geospatial/), but when you only need to test for exact equality, you don't need those and can treat your geo-coordinates like plain old data. So when you just add a vanilla index on the `loc` field and use a vanilla `find()` with the values you are searching, you will get your matches.